# Kubuntu 18.04 composition font artefacts

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, fonts, plasma-5, compositing

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and after a regular reboot, I started to have issues with the font rendering.

I don't know which packages were installed before the reboot.
Can anybody suggest me what should I check?

If I boot the system without composition and immediately after enabling it, everything is OK.

My system specs are:

- CPU: Intel i5-8350U
- GPU: Intel Graphics 620
- Composition: OpenGL 2.0

**Fonts in Desktop effects section**

[image: Fonts in Desktop effects section]

**Lines in Kate**

[image: Lines in Kate]

Comment: I found a workaround, this issue can be detected when the scale factor is changed from the display settings, but there is a chance to change the fonts DPI which leads to approx the same result but without this bug.

app: I forgot to mention, I'm using Thinkpad t480s